# How to set HTML table id from php?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to give my table cells id from php.
But with no succes.

This is what i got:

**PHP**

```
echo "<td class='edit' id='". echo $row['element_id']. "'>". echo $row['element_nr']."</td>";
```

Comment: `echo`ing an `echo` doesn't make a lot of sense eh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to remove the inner echo statements like this:

```
echo "<td class='edit' id='". $row['element_id']. "'>" . $row['element_nr'] . "</td>";
```

You can read more about concatenation here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @d00rman You're welcome! Have a nice day :D (BTW: If you want you can take a 2min tour here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour and see how the site works!)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling echo inside echo, remove the inner echo. Use the code below

```
echo "<td class='edit' id='". $row['element_id']. "'>" . $row['element_nr'] . "</td>";
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: What makes the difference from Rizier123's answer

Comment: Oh.. I didn't noticed his answer he submitted faster than me

Comment: Always check before you post :P